# Browserify- How to call node js code in chrome extension using browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension, browserify

I'm currently working a chrome extension that had node js on it.. and I can't call the require() code and got me an error (Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined). and when I searched that error it needs Browserify to worked. But unfortunately, I don't understand the Browserify and how to called it on chrome extension and node js. someone help?

Comment: Would you mind showing what 'node.js code" is in your chrome extensions? I guess what you mean is just some module management code however I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browserify is a bundler.  You use it to bundle your code and it's dependencies into a single Javascript file that you can then use in the browser / plugin.  It is important to understand that browserify doesn't process your require(...) statements on the fly like require.js does out of the box, but instead pre-compiles all those modules ahead of time.

At it's most basic:
`browserify yourCodeWithDependencies.js -o browserReadyBundle.js`

Hope this points you in the right direction.  Highly recommend you play with Browserify a bit to see what it does before trying to integrate it into your plugin development flow.